# How to make a linear-gradient drawable(not 45 degree times) in Android just like css background

Tags: android, css

In Android,I know that we can use LinearGradient to achieve a LinearGradientDrawable

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:angle="45"
    android:endColor="#0c75de"
    android:startColor="#57f16c"
    android:type="linear" />
```

There is a shortcoming,"android:angle" just can be 45 degree multiply.
And now i want to achieve a linear gradient drawable whose angle was not 45 degree multiply(such as 120 degree).How can I do it?

In CSS it is simple,just like

```css
p {
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #53ACD3, #FF5555);
}
```

Comment: rotate your gradient drawable: `RotateDrawable`

Comment: Thank you pskink,it's a good idea and I will try it.